# php file: use dlopen and dlsym. how

Tags: php, c++, shared-objects

I have myCode.so file created my linking a .c and .h file. I would like to call this .c file using the myCode.so and dlopen and dlsym . How to do that from php? I need some help! thx.

2.
Is there a way to import inside php (config.m4, php_example.h and php_example.c and example.php) a test.cpp code that uses the myCode.so for tests?

NEED SOME HELP! APPRECIATE

I am working in ubuntu (g++ comilper)

Comment: If I understand what you want then this tutorial for linking php against a dynamic library in C++ should help. http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486

Comment: the link it's about wrapping a class . i don;t want to expose the source code. i just want to link to thelibrar without including the .cpp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compiled a PHP extension with the PHP build system (`phpize && ./configure && make`), you only need to tell PHP to load the extension, and it will take care of dlopen etc:

```
extension=myCode.so
```

(myCode.so as to be in `extension_dir`)

For functions to be callable from PHP code, you have to use the PHP_FUNCTION macro (see other extensions for examples).

For the tests, look in the `tests` directory in other extensions.

Comment: thx for your answer. Usually in PHP_NEW_EXTENSION() it's needed the .c file that contains the PHP_FUNCTION macro and the .c file that has the code implemented. Can I change the .c file that conains the class methods with the .so file that i have? is it possible?